# Switch forms with tab control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a beginner in C#, so please bear with me. I have a form where I have a tab control, this tab control has 3 tabs. I am trying to show a form with each tab page. I am able to show a form on the first tab, but for some reason, the other two tabs do not load the forms. This is the code that I have. Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any suggestions?

```
private void MainTab_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        HomeScreen fHome = new HomeScreen();
        fHome.TopLevel = false;
        fHome.Visible = true;

        fHome.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        fHome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        MainOptions.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(fHome);
}


private void CustomerTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CustomerScreen fCustomer = new CustomerScreen();
        fCustomer.TopLevel = false;
        fCustomer.Visible = true;
        fCustomer.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        fCustomer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        MainOptions.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(fCustomer);
 }
```

edit:

More:

Also, in the tabcontrol- InitializeComponent I have the following

```
        // HomeTab
        // 
        this.HomeTab.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.HomeTab.Name = "HomeTab";
        this.HomeTab.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(677, 452);
        this.HomeTab.TabIndex = 0;
        this.HomeTab.Text = "Home";
        this.HomeTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.HomeTab.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.MainTab_Load);
        // 
        // CustomerTab
        // 
        this.CustomerTab.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.CustomerTab.Name = "CustomerTab";
        this.CustomerTab.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.CustomerTab.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(677, 452);
        this.CustomerTab.TabIndex = 1;
        this.CustomerTab.Text = "Customer";
        this.CustomerTab.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.CustomerTab.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CustomerTab_Click);
```

Comment: Check to make sure that your event handler is wired up properly. Have you stepped through the code to see if the `CustomerTab_Click` method is being called?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my previous post to show the event for "click" the CustomerTab

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the Show() method...

And a suggestion: I don't know what kind of Pattern you're using, but as a beginner, you should declare your forms outside those methods, as a variable within the class scope, so you can access then later...

```
private HomeScreen fHome = new HomeScreen();
private CustomerScreen fCustomer = new CustomerScreen();

private void MainTab_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fHome.TopLevel = false;
    fHome.Visible = true;
    fHome.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    fHome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    MainOptions.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(fHome);
    fHome.Show(); // add this
}

private void CustomerTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fCustomer.TopLevel = false;
    fCustomer.Visible = true;
    fCustomer.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    fCustomer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    MainOptions.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(fCustomer);
    fCustomer.Show(); // add this
}
```

There's a lot to improve here, but that's a start.

Comment: The first form is displaying because that `TabPage` is rendered on form load.  The others are not rendered until told to display.  So it is for all but the first that you will need `Show()`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The form will show if I click on the tab page, but it does not load if I only click on the tab button. How can I do that?

Comment: @AndersonRancan will you give me a link of a good tutorial to learn how to improve my C# programming?

Comment: @user4585914 I think you should read something first, than practice... code first is always more fun, but unfortunately some things we got just reading...

Do some search at CodeProject articles, nice place to start with examples:
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17640/Tabbed-MDI-Child-Forms
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2431/Custom-Tab-Controls-Tabbed-Frame-and-Tabbed-MDI

But first of all, Microsoft has some good free material about practices:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921345.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx
Old, but yet useful...